# From where the execution starts in Drupal

Tags: installation, bootstrapping

Generally in any HTML file execution starts from index.html and PHP file starts from index.php.

But in Drupal from which file the execution is started, i know that it is started from bootstrap file but what calls the bootstrap file ?

What is the execution sequence when i write http://example.com which will load/install drupal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.php** inside Drupal root folder is the starting point of execution. It calls the bootstrap functions. Please see the code inside drupal 7 index.php file below.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```